# Loading Angular component in a Knockout application - Angular elements

Tags: html, angular, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, angular-elements

I am trying to add a Angular web component in a KnockoutJS application using Angular elements. Following this method of creating individual elements - [*"Angular Elements — A Practical Introduction To Web Components With Angular 6"*](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6-52c0b3076c2c)

My Angular element uses angular material design and the base Knockout app is built using jQuery and bootstrap.

The idea here is that upon click of a button on the base Knockout app, a modal opens up showing the Angular element.

Knockout Code -

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: editContent" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                            Edit Content
                        </button>

<div class="modal video-modal" id="edit-content-info" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="video-modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <app-home-content></app-home-content>
                <script src="~/Content/edit-content-view/app-home-content.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    self.editContent = function () {
    $('#edit-content-info').modal('show');
}
```

PROBLEM -
The component loads up fine in the Knockout app, however I am not able to perform any operations on that component like clicking checkboxes, editing the text box etc. Also, those different tabs, upon clicking on them, nothing happens.

That being said, I tested this component outside of the knockout application, in plain vanilla HTML file, and everything works fine.

[image]

CODE

My Angular app set up -
App Module

```
import { Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { createCustomElement } from "@angular/elements";
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GeneralInfoComponent,
    ContentNavbarComponent,
    HomeContentComponent,
    EpisodeInfoComponent,
    KeywordsInfoComponent,
    ContributorsInfoComponent,
    AttachmentsInfoComponent,
    TechattributesInfoComponent,
    AudioprogramsInfoComponent,
    NotesInfoComponent,
    DetailsInfoComponent,
    SecurityInfoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeContentComponent],
  entryComponents: [HomeContentComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(HomeContentComponent, {
      injector: this.injector,
    });
    customElements.define("app-home-content", el);
  }
}
```

The `app-home-content` component has a nested a component called `app-content-navbar` and navbar component nests a series of components seen in the tabs in above screen capture

app-home-content html

```
    <div class="container">
      <app-content-navbar></app-content-navbar>
      <div class="save-content-info">
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

app-home-content ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home-content",
  templateUrl: "./home-content.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home-content.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class HomeContentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

app-content-navbar html

```
<div class="content-edit-dialog">
  <h3>Edit Content - 4049008</h3>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="General">
      <app-general-info></app-general-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Episode">
      <app-episode-info></app-episode-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Keywords">
      <app-keywords-info></app-keywords-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Contributors">
      <app-contributors-info></app-contributors-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Attachments">
      <app-attachments-info></app-attachments-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Tech Attributes"
      ><app-techattributes-info></app-techattributes-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Audio Programs">
      <app-audioprograms-info></app-audioprograms-info>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Notes"> <app-notes-info></app-notes-info> </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Details"> <app-details-info></app-details-info> </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Security">
      <app-security-info></app-security-info>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

Is there any specific way of implementing angular elements in KnockoutJS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bad_coder updated the question :)